# invoke angular compiler programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an Angular project, I have some (Markdown) files that have Angular expressions embedded within them, e.g.

```
<h2>Start markdown</h2>
{{1 + 1}} 
<h2>End markdown></h2>
```

Given the path to the markdown file, I need to pass the content of the file to the angular compiler and store the result in a scope variable, e.g. for the file above the result should be

```
<h2>Start markdown</h2>
2
<h2>End markdown></h2>
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to pass the contents of a file to the angular compiler programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that requires only the `$interpolate` service and the current `scope`:

```
var result = $interpolate("foo {{'app.name' | translate}} # bar")(scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct quick check shows that interpolate takes plain text so its

```
var yourmarkdownText = "<h1>{{somescopevariable}}</h1>"

$scope.asString = $interpolate(yourmarkdownText);
```

Comment: I need the result of the compilation to be a String (because the directive that converts the markdown to HTML takes a String). For my example above, will  `$scope.compiledAngular` return `"<h2>Start markdown</h2>2<h2>End markdown></h2>"` ?

Comment: @Dónal $compile returns a link function which can bind to a scope I will check if what you want is possible